# Applescript: check if a string contains empty string?

Tags: applescript

I have an applescript that gets a string at one point and checks if it contains another string that I inputted.

So lets says I have "Im a string" and I want to search if it contains "string". I have this working by using "if searchString is in mainString then...."

But if I pass it an empty string this should equate to true no matter what the string is, but for some reason it isnt working.

How could I check if an empty string is in another string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different languages are going to handle this differently, and what you are seeing here is how Applescript handles it [1]. Any empty string is exactly that: empty. `""` has no value in Applescript (but it's neither null or missing a value; there is just nothing in it). If you were comparing two empty strings, then they would equate to each other, otherwise either a string is empty or it isn't and populated string can't contain an empty string.

You'll have to check to see if the search string is empty *first* and then handle that accordingly.

[1] REALbasic won't find an empty string in a populated string either.

**update per comment:**

Yes, but I have alwasys found it better to do the calculations of the condition *outside* of the `if...then` block with Applescript:

```
set condition1 to true -- "true" being a calculation of some kind
set condition2 to true

if (condition1) and (condition2) then
    -- do something
end if
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to use the if statement in Applescript in the following way: "if [condition 1] or [condition 2] then ..." ?

Answer (score 1):

What about first checking whether the string-to-search-for is empty, and then return 'true'?